# React Page Refresh the Whole Page after Clicking on a link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've just started using reactJS and i am integrating an HTML admin template in react which has header, sidebar, footer and the main section content.

One thing i'm a bit curious is whenever i click links in the main section content, only the specific section dynamically loads, but when i click on links in sidebar the entire page reloads, why is it so? Below is the code that i'm following

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Components/Header';
import Content from './Components/Content';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar';

const App = () => {
    return(
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Header/>
                        <Sidebar/>
                        <Content/>
                        <Footer/>
                    </BrowserRouter>
              );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../stack.png';

const Header = () => {
return(
        <nav>
        </nav>
      );
 }

export default Header;
```

**Sidebar.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Sidebar = () => {
  return(
              <aside>
                <div className="main-menu menu-fixed menu-dark menu-accordion menu-shadow" data-scroll-to-active="true">
                  <div className="main-menu-content">
                    <ul className="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
                      <li style={{'margin': '25px 0 0 0'}} className="active nav-item">
                        <Link to="/dashboard">
                          <i className="ft-home"></i>
                            <span className="menu-title">
                              Dashboard
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item"><a href={void(0)}><i className="ft-plus"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Create</span></a>
                        <ul className="menu-content">
                          <li className=" menu-item">
                            <Link to="/create">
                              <span className="menu-title">
                                Create New
                              </span>
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                          <li className=" menu-item">
                            <Link to="/createxyz">
                              <span className="menu-title">
                                Create XYZ
                              </span>
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </aside>
            );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**Content.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Enter from './Enter';
import Enterxyz from './Enterxyz';

const Content = () => {
    return(
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/create" component={Enter} />
                        <Route path="/createxyz" component={Enterxyz} />
                    </Switch>
              );
}

export default Content;
```

**Footer.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

function Footer()
  {
    return(
                <footer className="footer footer-static footer-light navbar-border">
                  <p className="clearfix blue-grey lighten-2 text-sm-center mb-0 px-2">
                    <span className="float-md-left d-block d-md-inline-block">&copy; 2020 &nbsp;
                        <a className="text-bold-800 grey darken-2" href="">
                            xyz
                        </a> (All Rights Reserved)
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </footer>
              );
  }

export default Footer;
```

**Code snippet in import Enter from './Enter';**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Enter = () => {
    return(
                    <div className="app-content content">
                        <div className="content-wrapper">
                            <div className="content-body">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                        <div className="card" style={{'height': 'auto'}}>
                                            <div className="card-header">
                                                <h4 className="card-title" id="basic-layout-form">Create New Client</h4>
                                                <a className="heading-elements-toggle"><i className="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>
                                                <div className="heading-elements">
                                                    <ul className="list-inline mb-0">
                                                        <li><Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link></li>
                                                        <li><i className="ft-chevrons-right"></i></li>
                                                        <li><a>Create</a></li>
                                                        <li><i className="ft-chevrons-right"></i></li>
                                                        <li><Link to="/create">Enter New</Link></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              );
}

export default Enter;
```

in the `Enter` code snippet there are 2 links(Breadcrumbs) when i click on them the page loads dynamically without refresh.

But when i click on the links in sidebar, the entire page reloads to display the content, why is it so? What is wrong?